# Script to plug into Google Chrome Dev tools to find overflow:hidden in DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I can't find which parent element has overflow:hidden for the life of me. Does someone have a script I can plugin to chrome dev tools to search for it?

Comment: ctrl-shft-i in chrome

Comment: The command doesn't seem to be doing anything on my mac. I also tried variations with the command button.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/451954/how-do-i-use-chrome-developer-debugging-shortcuts-on-a-mac